# How to solve App Crash when end call Android WebRTC

Tags: android, webrtc

I'm using WebRTC Android Library to create video call app.
But sometimes, when I finish the Activity, app will get crash.
I don't know is my close flow wrong or library itself.

I've notice that error point to signal_thread.
Because this app designed using in local network, so I didn't add STUN and IceCandidate Server to PeerConnection.

Also, I'm using latest library

```
implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006'
```

Code when I close up:

```
    private void close() {

    if (localVideoView != null) {
        localVideoView.release();
        localVideoView = null;
    }

    if (remoteVideoView != null) {
        remoteVideoView.release();
        remoteVideoView = null;
    }

    if (peerConnection != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "peerConnection close");
        peerConnection.dispose();
    }

    if (audioSource != null) {
        audioSource.dispose();
        audioSource = null;
        Log.e(TAG, "audioSource close");
    }

    if (videoCapturer != null) {
        try {
            videoCapturer.stopCapture();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        videoCapturer.dispose();
        videoCapturer = null;
        Log.e(TAG, "videoCapture close");
    }

    if (videoSource != null) {
        videoSource.dispose();
        videoSource = null;
        Log.e(TAG, "videoSource close");
    }

    if (surfaceTextureHelper != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceTextureHelper close");
        surfaceTextureHelper.dispose();
        surfaceTextureHelper = null;
    }

    if (mediaStreamLocal != null) {
        while (mediaStreamLocal.audioTracks.size() > 0) {
            mediaStreamLocal.removeTrack(mediaStreamLocal.audioTracks.get(0));
            Log.e(TAG, "audioTrack close");
        }
        while (mediaStreamLocal.videoTracks.size() > 0) {
            mediaStreamLocal.removeTrack(mediaStreamLocal.videoTracks.get(0));
            Log.e(TAG, "videoTrack close");
        }
        mediaStreamLocal = null;
        Log.e(TAG, "mediaStream close");
    }

    if (peerConnectionFactory != null) {
        peerConnectionFactory.dispose();
        Log.e(TAG, "peerConnectionFactory close");
    }

    if (eglBaseContext != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "eglBaseContext close");
        eglBaseContext = null;
    }

    PeerConnectionFactory.stopInternalTracingCapture();
    PeerConnectionFactory.shutdownInternalTracer();
    Log.e(TAG, "close done");
}
```

Error message when crash:

```
--------- beginning of crash
03-03 14:05:31.630 26351 28454 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 28454 (signaling_threa), pid 26351 (getupsetting_ap)
03-03 14:05:31.753 28489 28489 I crash_dump64: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
03-03 14:05:31.758 28489 28489 I crash_dump64: performing dump of process 26351 (target tid = 28454)
03-03 14:05:31.764 28489 28489 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-03 14:05:31.764 28489 28489 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'asus/WW_Z01RD/ASUS_Z01R_1:10/QKQ1.191008.001/WW_100.10.107.123_20210131:user/release-keys'
03-03 14:05:31.764 28489 28489 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
03-03 14:05:31.764 28489 28489 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
03-03 14:05:31.765 28489 28489 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2022-03-03 14:05:31+0800
03-03 14:05:31.765 28489 28489 F DEBUG   : pid: 26351, tid: 28454, name: signaling_threa  >>> org.getupsetting_ap <<<
03-03 14:05:31.765 28489 28489 F DEBUG   : uid: 10614
03-03 14:05:31.765 28489 28489 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
03-03 14:05:31.765 28489 28489 F DEBUG   : Cause: null pointer dereference
03-03 14:05:31.765 28489 28489 F DEBUG   :     x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000000005  x2  0000000000000001  x3  000000739b95d000
03-03 14:05:31.765 28489 28489 F DEBUG   :     x4  0000000000000001  x5  00000073a43da8a5  x6  5500ff315500ff30  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
03-03 14:05:31.765 28489 28489 F DEBUG   :     x8  88b5a5d1c44b6fe5  x9  88b5a5d1c44b6fe5  x10 0000000000430000  x11 0000000000000001
03-03 14:05:31.765 28489 28489 F DEBUG   :     x12 0000000000000000  x13 0000000012f80670  x14 0000000000000012  x15 00000000000000ff
03-03 14:05:31.765 28489 28489 F DEBUG   :     x16 0000000000000000  x17 00000000000000d7  x18 000000736bedc000  x19 000000739be3aa00
03-03 14:05:31.765 28489 28489 F DEBUG   :     x20 0000000000000005  x21 000000736de1c020  x22 000000736de1ba10  x23 000000736de1c020
03-03 14:05:31.765 28489 28489 F DEBUG   :     x24 000000736ef9dab8  x25 00000000ffffffff  x26 000000736de1c020  x27 000000748e620020
03-03 14:05:31.765 28489 28489 F DEBUG   :     x28 0000000000000000  x29 000000736de1bac0
03-03 14:05:31.765 28489 28489 F DEBUG   :     sp  000000736de1ba00  lr  000000736f545700  pc  000000736f54570c
03-03 14:05:31.767 28489 28489 F DEBUG   : 
03-03 14:05:31.767 28489 28489 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
03-03 14:05:31.767 28489 28489 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 000000000062870c  /data/app/org.getupsetting_ap-nOEyGd0pleQwgSv_ZsLzkw==/base.apk!libjingle_peerconnection_so.so (offset 0x16c000) (BuildId: d011a5fc83d6e795)
03-03 14:05:31.767 28489 28489 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 0000000000628440  /data/app/org.getupsetting_ap-nOEyGd0pleQwgSv_ZsLzkw==/base.apk!libjingle_peerconnection_so.so (offset 0x16c000) (BuildId: d011a5fc83d6e795)
03-03 14:05:31.767 28489 28489 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 000000000026f3b8  /data/app/org.getupsetting_ap-nOEyGd0pleQwgSv_ZsLzkw==/base.apk!libjingle_peerconnection_so.so (offset 0x16c000) (BuildId: d011a5fc83d6e795)
03-03 14:05:31.767 28489 28489 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 000000000025c08c  /data/app/org.getupsetting_ap-nOEyGd0pleQwgSv_ZsLzkw==/base.apk!libjingle_peerconnection_so.so (offset 0x16c000) (BuildId: d011a5fc83d6e795)
03-03 14:05:31.767 28489 28489 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 000000000025b098  /data/app/org.getupsetting_ap-nOEyGd0pleQwgSv_ZsLzkw==/base.apk!libjingle_peerconnection_so.so (offset 0x16c000) (BuildId: d011a5fc83d6e795)
03-03 14:05:31.767 28489 28489 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 000000000025c544  /data/app/org.getupsetting_ap-nOEyGd0pleQwgSv_ZsLzkw==/base.apk!libjingle_peerconnection_so.so (offset 0x16c000) (BuildId: d011a5fc83d6e795)
03-03 14:05:31.767 28489 28489 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 00000000000e6890  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36) (BuildId: cf739dbc84bcc78f7a1500721bfb3758)
03-03 14:05:31.767 28489 28489 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 0000000000084b6c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: cf739dbc84bcc78f7a1500721bfb3758)
```

Also, I'm using add2lin to find error on libjingle_peerconnection_so.so, and that tool show the function below:

```
Java_org_webrtc_TurnCustomizer_nativeFreeTurnCustomizer
Java_org_webrtc_Logging_nativeLog
Java_org_webrtc_Metrics_nativeGetAndReset
```

Comment: I have this issue constantly for a few years now. Nothing helped, including disabling hardware accelerator. Patching memory leaks using Canary may help reduce it though.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue few days back, the following might solve your problem:

1. Invalidating Android Studio's cache and restarting it.
2. Re-install the app(if physical device) or wipe data and do cool boot(in case of Emulator).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After try several times and search relation question on the internet. This problem have temporart been solved by turn hardwareAccelerated off, but maybe that isn't the right method. I will continue to follow this issue.
`android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`

Comment: Yes, I think it is related to the hardware only.

Comment: Hi @terry258369, I'm facing the same issue and chanced upon this post while researching for solutions. Can you tell me where we need to place `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`?

Also were you able to find the root cause for this issue?